# Seperate the rows in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am learning how to use Tkinter, but I found that using .grid(), the row above will affect the rows below.
I'm wondering is there a solution for this problem? The first row is affecting the checkboxes below. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r50iX.jpg)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=900, height=1300)
canvas1.create_window(400, 200, window=tkinter.ttk.Separator(canvas1, orient='vertical').grid(row=0, column=2))

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="The food Info you want to know")
label1.config(font=("helvetica", 14))
label1.grid(row=0, column=2)
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

I tried ttk.separator, but it seems not to seperate the rows. So I'm wondering is there something I've done wrong.

Comment: what do you mean the first row is affecting the checkboxes? affecting how? What does the code you provided have to do with the photo?

Comment: The Label and Entry should either have `column=0, columnspan=5` specified, so that their width isn't being considered part of only one column of Checkboxes, OR they should be in an entirely separate Frame, not part of the grid layout of the Checkboxes at all.

Comment: What do you want to do on this line `canvas1.create_window(400, 200, window=label1.grid(row=0, column=2))` actually? This is the same as running `label1.grid(row=0, column=2)` and then `canvas1.create_window(400, 200, window=None)`.

Comment: @Alexander from the photo you can see the second column is affected by the size of the entry and the label above.

Comment: @acw1668 I first tried to use ```tk.pack()``` to place the elements, but later I found maybe ```tk.grid``` will be easier to implement, so I accidentially forgot to comment them out. Sorry for the bad coding.

Comment: canvas1.create_window(400, 400, window=tkinter.ttk.Separator(canvas1, orient='vertical'))
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=2)

Comment: canvas1.grid(row=0....  and  label1.grid(row=1....   and entry1.grid(row=2....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the misleading of the question, I am trying to simplify the code so that the question would be easier to answer, but it seems to confuse.

@jasonharper gave the solution to my question, after using `column=0, columnspan=5`, the rows below (checkboxes) weren't affected by the size of the columns above.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsLCk.jpg) [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odVcW.jpg)

Comment: Better approach is put those checkboxes in a frame.